# Limit of $\sin(x)\cos(1/x)$ as $x\to 0$

Tags: calculus

I am at the second lesson of my Calculus 1 course. I found below explanation of the limit $\sin(x)\cos(1/x)$ as $x\to 0$. I plan something similar to use as the answer of my homework. My concern is: is this solution of the limit correct? Can we conclude from the table that limit is approaching to $0$ although it is oscillating and changing the sign?

[image]

Comment: You need to observe that $cos (1/x)$ is bounded and then use [squeeze theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem).

Comment: IMO, you can't conclude anything from tables at all ever.  You see a bunch of points where it appears so but you haven't checked them all and maybe in the very next one you try it will blow up..... *BUT*.......

Comment: Tables are good to guess what you have to prove. But, in almost all the cases, don't constitute a proof.

Comment: At my second class of Calculus 1 I am allowed only to use tables, not advanced differentiation techniques.

Comment: $-1 \le \cos (anything) \le 1$ so $-\sin x \le \sin x \cos \frac 1x \le \sin x$.  And we can show that $\sin x \to 0$ and therefore $-\sin x\to 0$ and $0 \le \lim \sin x\cos \frac 1x \le 0$.

Comment: "At my second class of Calculus 1 I am allowed only to use tables, not advanced differentiation techniques."  I'd advise transfering to a different class....... :\

Comment: Haha. We are still learning basics ;) advanced things come soon ;)

Answer (score 3):

Yes your guess from the table is correct, indeed since $\;\forall \theta\in\mathbb R\;$ $\;-1\le \cos \theta \le 1$, for $x>0$ we have that

$$-\sin x \le \sin x \cdot \cos \left(\frac1x\right)\le \sin x$$

and since $\sin x \to 0^+$ by [**squeeze theorem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) the limit is equal to $0$. For $x<0$ we can use a similar argument.

Comment: Why not use a presentation with absolute value, it's a bit more standard I think ?

Comment: @zwim I agree with your observation and of course the notation with absolute value is moe standard. In that case, since the asker is starting with calculus, I prefer to use the simpler notation.

Comment: If you start with $-1\leq\cos\left(\frac{1}x\right)\leq 1$ and multiply through by $\sin(x)$, you actually need to make sure that $\sin(x)>0$ in order to preserve the direction of the inequalities. For example, the inequality you wrote down is not true for $x=-\pi/4$, say. So there are actually two cases: $x\rightarrow 0^-$ and $x\rightarrow 0^+$. The spirit is correct though!

Comment: @Ehsaan Yes of course! Thanks to have pointed that out.

Comment: [This graph on Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jcr0c5ptmx) should show why using abs is so important.